# Hide status bar in Launch Screen

Tags: swift, swift3, uistatusbar, launch-screen

By default the launch screen provides a status bar. Is it possible to hide the status bar in launch screen like a Twitter app ( iOS ).

Comment: In Your Info.plist add: `Status bar is initially hidden YES`

Comment: @Rocky Thanks for your help! It's just works.

Comment: @Rocky It's should be the answer not the comment.

Comment: added as answer with additional detail :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To Hide Status Bar initially on launch screen, set `Hide status bar` check mark on ✓ [image]

**OR**

In Your Info.plist add: `Status bar is initially hidden` `YES`.

The above both option having same impact.

**Additionally**

To Hide Status Bar on specific ViewController `override` `prefersStatusBarHidden` with `true`

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    return true
}
```

Comment: The first option is useless. :) Second one is works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The first one is useful too, but you need to look for it in `AppTarget -> General  ->  Deployment` Info (not in the storyboard)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine at 2023.9.11

**Envrironment**

```
MacOS 13.5.2 (Ventura)

Xcode 14.3.1

Simulator 16.4
```

checking your target Info.plist View controller-based status bar appearance setup for solutions

#### Solutions

---

##### View controller-based status bar appearance | `NO`

Steps:

1. setup in project file (.proj) -> General -> Deployment Info -> Hide status bar -> v checked!

[image]

2. Show status bar or decide status bar color again, write below code in your project at any lifecycle. Of course you can set in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

> ```
> [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
> [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent;
> ```

`language: Objective-C`

---

##### View controller-based status bar appearance | `YES`

1. setup in project file (.proj) -> Build Settings -> Info.plist Values -> Status Bar Initially Hidden -> fill YES!

[image]

2. override preferredStatusBarStyle or prefersStatusBarHidden in each you UIViewController

> ```
> class ViewController: UIViewController {
>     
>     override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
>
>     override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return false }
> }
> ```

`language: Swift`

Comment: Why are the Objective-C and Swift solutions completely different? The language is irrelevant. And the Objective-C code you provide is long deprecated.

Comment: After September 2021, the absence of the "View controller-based status bar appearance" setting in a new Swift project's Xcode settings indicates that the default behavior is to use the value "YES," meaning that each view controller can independently control the status bar appearance. So let me edit the answer, the objective-c solutions is the case for value "NO"

Comment: Normally, objective c project is created before 2021, its "View controller-based status bar appearance" setup will be NO. The Swift project nowadays normally will set to be YES. Real difference is setup for "View controller-based status bar appearance" in info.plist. The language is just for showing common examples, you can choose either one u like.