# How to hide Status bar for a particular screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, statusbar

I'm new to flutter.

I want to hide status bar only in splash screen. I have a specific color for the status bar too. Here is the code where i specified color for status bar.

i have used the following code in main method to give a specific color.

```
   SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarColor: colorStyle.statusBar, // status bar color
```

Now I want to hide status bar only in Splash screen.

When i used

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

in splash screen ,the status bar hide throughout the app.

How can i solve this problem.Please find me a solution.

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score -1):

This should be done for the android specifically, if i am not wrong then you can use the below code

Use

```
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

and for the ios you do the following steps

n Your Info.plist add: Status bar is initially hidden YES.

The above both option having same impact.

Additionally

To Hide Status Bar on specific ViewController override prefersStatusBarHidden with true

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    return true
}
```

if you are still confused the check the links below

ios :[Hide status bar in Launch Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718697/hide-status-bar-in-launch-screen/48740344)

android :[Android status bar hide/change color in splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355749/android-status-bar-hide-change-color-in-splash-screen/44356160)

you can check this also:
[How to hide Android StatusBar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877288/how-to-hide-android-statusbar-in-flutter)